# Using (MaterializeCSS), how to initialize Picker components without freezing the browser?

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

**Description**

I am trying to write a small `to-do list` project using `materialize css` library. 
In my project, I have a button which triggers a modal containing a form with two picker elements - date and time. The first time I pick either the date or time, everything works, but if I try to edit my initial choice - the browser freezes. I use the latest version of Firefox. Also, I pass option parameter `container` to both pickers to make sure they render using all available space instead of only using the space provided by the modal which calls them. I hope this makes sense. What did I do wrong? How to ensure my browser doesn't freeze executing the code below.

**Docs**

[Picker](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html)

**Code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

    <title>task manager</title>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css'>

    <style>
        button{ width: 100%; }
        input{ text-align: center; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>

        <div class='fixed-action-btn'>
            <button class='btn-floating btn-large red'>
                <i class='large material-icons'>dehaze</i>
            </button>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <button class='btn-floating green modal-trigger' data-target='add-task'>
                        <i class='material-icons'>add</i>
                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class='modal' id='add-task'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
                <h3>NEW TASK</h3>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col s12'>
                        <div class='input-field'>
                            <input id='task' type='text'>
                            <label for='task'>enter task</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col s6'>
                        <div class='input-field'>
                            <input class='datepicker' id='task-date' type='text'>
                            <label for='task-date'>select date</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='col s6'>
                        <div class='input-field'>
                            <input class='timepicker' id='task-time' type='text'>
                            <label for='task-time'>select time</label>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col s12'>
                        <div class='input-field'>
                            <select id='priority-task'>
                                <option value='low'>low</option>
                                <option value='moderate'>moderate</option>
                                <option value='hight'>high</option>
                            </select>
                            <label for='task-priority'>select priority</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-footer'>
                    <button class='btn waves-effect waves-light'>submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script> 
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js'></script>
    <script>
       document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
           const container = document.querySelector('.container');

           const date_picker = document.querySelector('.datepicker');
           const time_picker = document.querySelector('.timepicker');

           const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
           const select = document.querySelector('select');
           const menu = document.querySelector('.fixed-action-btn');

           M.FloatingActionButton.init(menu);

           M.FormSelect.init(select);

           M.Datepicker.init(date_picker, {container: container});
           M.Timepicker.init(time_picker, {container: '.container'});

           M.Modal.init(modal);
       });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in version *1.0.0-rc.1*.
Use those new CDN links when importing materialize style and script.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.1/css/materialize.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.1/js/materialize.js

Comment: I didn't realize there was a different version, I went with the one presented on the main website :s but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I saw that too, that why I provided the links in the answer ;) You're not to blame !